# SQL cumulative previous 12 months - breakdown per month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can anyone assist in a sql statement I am trying to write? I'm using SSRS r1 (either sql or ssrs solution is fine)

How do I:

- show count measure split by month and year
- for each of those months, I want to count the previous cumulative 12 months

e.g.

```
2012 jan: counts feb 2011 - jan 2012
2012 feb: counts mar 2011 - feb 2012
2012 mar: counts apr 2011 - mar 2012
```

I have started this code but it's incorrect, however it gives you an idea of what I am trying to achieve (this issue is I have to calc month and year from a date)

```
select 
    count(a.measure) count
    ,month(a.StartDate)
    ,year(a.StartDate)
from
    a
where 
    a.StartDate >=  DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@datepromt)-12,0) as startdateYrAgo --1st month 1 year ago 01/01/2012 
    and a.StartDate <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@datepromt)+1,0)) as startdateEOM --last day of month 31/01/2013
group by 
    month(a.StartDate)
    ,year(a.StartDate)
```

Comment: what have you tried? did you check the date functions already? what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you read the FAQ to learn how to ask a question in StackOverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). A good rule of thumb is: a question starting with "I need" is not a good question.

Comment: What you want to see for `dec 2011`?

Comment: do u want a count(value) from table where date_value < input_date - 1 year

Comment: have started this code but its incorrect (as I need to prompt for date, work out the count for previous 12 months for EACH month, then display the month and date), however gives you an idea of what I am trying to achieve (this issue is I have to calc month and year from a date)

I have updated the question with code thanks

Comment: @user2001784 - if you want good answers for this question, consider building a demo recordset and your initial attempt on SQLFiddle, so readers will be _easily_ able to "fork and fiddle" for you.

Comment: I tried to use SQLFiddle and got stuck. CREATE TABLE test
(
id int,
groupId int,
startDate date 
)

INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (1, 1, '01-01-2012')

Comment: For dec 2011 I need to show 01-jan-2011 to 31-dec-2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an idea for the query, it have to look something like below;

```
SELECT 
 periods.year
,periods.month
,measures.cnt
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      year = YEAR(StartDate)
    , month = MONTH(StartDate)
    , month_running = DATEDIFF(mm, 0, StartDate) 
    FROM a
    GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate), MONTH(StartDate), DATEDIFF(mm, 0, StartDate) 
) periods
JOIN (
    SELECT month_running = DATEDIFF(mm, 0, StartDate), cnt = COUNT(measure) 
    FROM a
    GROUP BY DATEDIFF(mm, 0, StartDate) 
) measures
ON measures.month_running BETWEEN periods.month_running - 12 AND periods.month_running - 1
```

Comment: Really nice bit of sql thanks. Took me a while to figure out that it was returning multiple lines for each month but this was the monthly figure for the previous months and I then had to total them to get the cumulative month total.